# In my html script the spacing between the forms is not even

Tags: html

The spacing between the state and red forms is not the same as between red and green. I haven't added any padding or border only to the buttons. I tried adding them to the forms but didn't work. Image and code are below. I am not that good at html and css. This is a basic webpage supposed to work with another program.

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U6QR.jpg

```
    <html><head>
  <title>ESP Alarm Clock</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Mono&display=swap');
    html {font-family: 'Space Mono',monospace; display: inline-block; text-align: center; background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(63,238,230,1) 0%, rgba(252,68,69,1) 100%);}
    h1 {font-family: 'Space Mono',monospace;font-size: 3.0rem;color: #000000;}
    h2 {font-family: 'Space Mono',monospace;font-size: 2.0rem;color: #000000;}
    h3 {font-family: 'Space Mono',monospace;font-size: 1.2rem;font-weight: 700;color: #000000;}
    input[type = submit] {
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            border: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #ffffff;
            padding: 8px 8px;
            margin: 8px 8px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-family: 'Space Mono',monospace;
         }
    input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
                            color: #ffffff;
                            opacity: 1;

    }
    body {max-width: 900px; margin:0px auto; padding-bottom: 25px;}
  </style>
  </script></head><body>
  <h1>Light Control</h1>
  <h2>Color: %R%,%G%,%B%,%bright%</h2>
  <form action="/get" target="hidden-form">
    <h3>State: <input type="number"  name="state"style="background-color:white; 
              border: solid 1px #6E6E6E;
              height: 20px; 
              font-size:18px; 
              color:#bbb" 
              placeholder="1 = on,0 = off">
    <input type="submit"  value="Submit" onclick="submitMessage()">
  </form><br>
  <form action="/get" target="hidden-form">
    Red: <input type="number"  name="R"style="background-color:white; 
              border: solid 1px #6E6E6E;
              height: 20px; 
              font-size:18px; 
              color:#bbb" 
              placeholder="0-255">
    <input type="submit"  value="Submit" onclick="submitMessage()">
  </form><br>
  <form action="/get" target="hidden-form">
    Green: <input type="number"  name="G"style="background-color:white; 
              border: solid 1px #6E6E6E;
              height: 20px; 
              font-size:18px; 
              color:#bbb" 
              placeholder="0-255">
    <input type="submit"  value="Submit" onclick="submitMessage()">
  </form><br>
  <form action="/get" target="hidden-form">
    Blue: <input type="number"  name="B"style="background-color:white; 
              border: solid 1px #6E6E6E;
              height: 20px; 
              font-size:18px; 
              color:#bbb" 
              placeholder="0-255">
    <input type="submit"  value="Submit" onclick="submitMessage()">
  </form><br>
  <form action="/get" target="hidden-form">
    Brightness: <input type="number"  name="bright"style="background-color:white; 
              border: solid 1px #6E6E6E;
              height: 20px; 
              font-size:18px; 
              color:#bbb" 
              placeholder="0-255">
    <input type="submit"  value="Submit" onclick="submitMessage()">
  </form><br>
  <iframe style="display:none" name="hidden-form"></iframe>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unclosed `h3` tag in your first form. Remove it and everything works fine.

```
<form action="/get" target="hidden-form">
    State: <input type="number"  name="state"style="background-color:white; 
              border: solid 1px #6E6E6E;
              height: 20px; 
              font-size:18px; 
              color:#bbb" 
              placeholder="1 = on,0 = off">
  <input type="submit"  value="Submit" onclick="submitMessage()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you had some invalid HTML. First, you have an unclosed `h3` tag here:

```
 <form action="/get" target="hidden-form">
    <h3>State:
```

You also have a random `</script>` at the top of your page for no reason. That should be removed.

```
  </style>
  </script></head><body>
  <h1>Light Control</h1>
  <h2>Color: %R%,%G%,%B%,%bright%</h2>
  <form action="/get" target="hidden-form">
```

Also, I'm not sure about other browsers, but Chrome sets a margin bottom on the `form` element. If you are using `<br />` tags, then you probably want to set the margin-bottom of the form to 0.

I've cleaned up your code, here it is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ESP Alarm Clock</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style>
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Mono&display=swap");
      html {
        font-family: "Space Mono", monospace;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        background: linear-gradient(
          90deg,
          rgba(63, 238, 230, 1) 0%,
          rgba(252, 68, 69, 1) 100%
        );
      }
      h1 {
        font-family: "Space Mono", monospace;
        font-size: 3rem;
        color: #000000;
      }
      h2 {
        font-family: "Space Mono", monospace;
        font-size: 2rem;
        color: #000000;
      }
      h3 {
        font-family: "Space Mono", monospace;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #000000;
      }
      input[type="submit"] {
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        border: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        padding: 8px 8px;
        margin: 8px 8px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-family: "Space Mono", monospace;
      }
      input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        color: #ffffff;
        opacity: 1;
      }
      body {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
      }

      form {
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Light Control</h1>
    <h2>Color: %R%,%G%,%B%,%bright%</h2>
    <form action="/get" target="hidden-form">
      State:
      <input
        type="number"
        name="state"
        style="
          background-color: white;
          border: solid 1px #6e6e6e;
          height: 20px;
          font-size: 18px;
          color: #bbb;
        "
        placeholder="1 = on,0 = off"
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitMessage()" />
    </form>
    <br />
    <form action="/get" target="hidden-form">
      Red:
      <input
        type="number"
        name="R"
        style="
          background-color: white;
          border: solid 1px #6e6e6e;
          height: 20px;
          font-size: 18px;
          color: #bbb;
        "
        placeholder="0-255"
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitMessage()" />
    </form>
    <br />
    <form action="/get" target="hidden-form">
      Green:
      <input
        type="number"
        name="G"
        style="
          background-color: white;
          border: solid 1px #6e6e6e;
          height: 20px;
          font-size: 18px;
          color: #bbb;
        "
        placeholder="0-255"
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitMessage()" />
    </form>
    <br />
    <form action="/get" target="hidden-form">
      Blue:
      <input
        type="number"
        name="B"
        style="
          background-color: white;
          border: solid 1px #6e6e6e;
          height: 20px;
          font-size: 18px;
          color: #bbb;
        "
        placeholder="0-255"
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitMessage()" />
    </form>
    <br />
    <form action="/get" target="hidden-form">
      Brightness:
      <input
        type="number"
        name="bright"
        style="
          background-color: white;
          border: solid 1px #6e6e6e;
          height: 20px;
          font-size: 18px;
          color: #bbb;
        "
        placeholder="0-255"
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitMessage()" />
    </form>
    <br />
    <iframe style="display: none;" name="hidden-form"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is part of a bigger html script so thats what the script tag was for.